# Trouble Solving a system of linear ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve:

$x' = 9y$; $x(0) = -2$

$y' = -16x$; $y(0) = -4$.

I am unsure how to even begin. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the second equation
$$x=-\frac{y'}{16}$$
$$x'=-\frac{y''}{16}$$
substitute in the first equation to get
$$-\frac{y''}{16}=9y$$
$$y''+144y=0$$
this homogeneous D.E so 
the general solution is
$$y=C_1\cos 12t+C_2\sin 12t$$
at $y(0)=-4$
$$-4=C_1(1)$$
$$C_1=-4$$
$$y=-4\cos 12t+C_2\sin 12t$$
now derive it
$$y'=48\sin 12t+12C_2\cos 12t$$
but 
$$x=-\frac{y'}{16}$$
so
$$x=-\frac{1}{16}(48\sin 12t+12C_2\cos 12t)$$
use the $x(0)=-2$ to find the $C_2$
$$-2=-\frac{1}{16}(0+12C_2(1))$$

Comment: Thanks. So now that I have $y = -4\cos(12x) + C_2\sin(12x)$, how can I use the fact that $x(0) =-2$?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether I have added more details

Comment: This is not quite adding more details as I have already deduced that $C_1 = -4$ which is why I wrote in my comment that $y = -4\cos(12x) + C_2\sin(12x)$ as I am trying to find what $C_2$ is.

Comment: One thing I thought about doing is noticing that $x = \dfrac{-y'}{16} = (-1)[\dfrac{48\sin(12x)+12C_2\cos(12x)}{16}]$ and then taking $x(0) = -4 \implies C_2 = dfrac{-64}{12}$

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether now , is it enough or not?

Comment: Okay yes that is much clearer. That is exactly what I did as well so we are in complete agreeance and you have helped me a lot on this.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to solve these functions as a matrix of linear differential equations. However, given the simple nature of this one, we can solve it better by substitution.

Substituting $y = x'/9$ into the second equation, we have $x''/9 = -16x \rightarrow x'' = -144x$. Do you know how to solve this equation?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{hint}$

Taking the derivative of one of the equations we find
$$
x'' = 9y' = 9(-16x) = - (3\cdot 4)^2 x
$$
Solve for $x$ and then plug into the remaining ode and solve for $y$ .

Or you can go with the full matrix method.